# Можно ли "прицепить" чат комментариев к уже существующему чату?

Tags: обсуждение, чат

Комментариев в теме стало много, модератор вынес их в чат. Можно ли этот чат (поскольку там описана куча полезных вещей по теме) скопировать/прицепить/прикрепить к другому чату, чтобы ничего не потерялось, и можно было бы ссылаться на конкретные реплики?

Чтобы было понятнее, покажу на примере:
есть [чат, посвященный проблемам биоинформатики](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69687/), появился [чат, касающийся одной из проблем](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72761/discussion-on-question-by-viktor-tomilov------). Можно ли второй прицепить к первому? Если нельзя сделать это в активной форме, можно ли как-то создать пассивный линк?

Comment: что значит _прицепить_?

Comment: @Grundy В идеале: уничтожить второй чат, перенеся все сообщения в первый, ну, и, поправив ссылку на чат в сообщении, хотя последнее можно сделать и руками. Термин "прицепить" - из начала 90х, когда были популярны чатовые комнаты с разделением проблем

Comment: Переносить комментарии может owner чата

Comment: Можно попросить модераторов. Но было бы удобнее создать необязательную дополнительную опцию при создании вопроса - в какой чат перенести комментарии в случае если их становится много.

Comment: @Grundy А кто есть owner чата в данном случае?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, забавно, но никто: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/72761/discussion-on-question-by-viktor-tomilov------

Comment: В этом случае перенести могут модераторы

Comment: @Grundy О том и речь, что "нихто" :(

Comment: Нельзя, там муть получается... Лучше просто дать ссылку на весь чат.

Comment: @Qwertiy А он не помре? Данные, то бишь, диалоги в нём останутся?

Comment: Диалоги останутся, но чат может замёрзнуть (стать read-only) из-за отсутствия активности в нём.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, даже если чат замёрзнет и закроется, он будет доступен в readonly-режиме. Ну и модераторы могут разморозить.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот последнее - важно :)